# jQuery counting elements in a class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can anyone explain why `alert($('.letter').length);` returns (4) when you drop a letter into the grey box in this jsfiddle?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6yEx/)

```
$(function () {
    $('.drag').draggable({
        cursor: 'move',
        revert: 'invalid',
        helper: 'clone',
    });
    $('.droppable').droppable({
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: function (event, ui) {
            return true;
        },
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var correct = 0;
            var dropId = $(this).attr('id');
            var letterId = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
            var letId = dropId.substring(0, 1);
            var count = $(this).children().length;

            if (count < 1) {
                if (letterId == dropId) {
                    $(this)
                        .addClass("correct");
                    $(this).append(ui.draggable);
                } else {
                    $(this)
                        .addClass('wrong');
                    $(this).append(ui.draggable);
                }
            }
            $('.droppable').each(function () {
                var letId = $(this).children().attr('id');
                var dropId = $(this).attr('id');

                if (letId === undefined) {
                    $(this).removeClass('correct');
                    $(this).removeClass('wrong');
                }
                if (letId == dropId) {
                    correct++;
                }
            });
            alert($('.letter').length);
        }
    });
});
```

If you drop a second letter into a second box, you still get 4, so I don't see the appends doing anything.

Comment: Post a complete code example *in your question*. If jsFiddle is inaccessible then your question loses all value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a clone helper on the page at that time with the `.letter` class, so the length of all the elements found on the page at that point in time is 4.

I've updated the fiddle to alert the `class` of the last element, which is the helper class (you can tell by the `dragging` class appended to the element).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6yEx/2/)

To get a count of all the letters excluding the helper, try this selector:

```
$('.letter:not(".ui-draggable-dragging")');
```

Since the helper is the object being dragged, JQuery-ui adds a `dragging` class to it which you can key in on.

[Fiddle with updated count](http://jsfiddle.net/M6yEx/4/)

Comment: ah, i see.  how can i count .letters without that helper clone?  or i guess, how do i unset that clone before i count?

Comment: If you remove `helper : 'clone'` from the setup, there will only be 3.

Comment: @bart2puck Updated the question with a selector that will exclude the helper class